# Make 3D scatterplot from multidimensional array

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

I have a 3 dimensional hdf5 file that I want to plot in R as a scatter plot.

Here's my code so far which seems to load in the data just fine.  But the scatterplot function wants x,y,z as arguments and I'm not sure what to tell it:

```
> source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
> biocLite("rhdf5")
> library(rhdf5)
> mydata <- h5read('/Users/greg/1611_data.h5','dataset_1')
> str(mydata)
 int [1:194, 1:627, 1:269] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
> install.packages("scatterplot3d")
> library(scatterplot3d)
> scatterplot3d(mydata)
Error in xyz.coords(x = x, y = y, z = z, xlab = xlabel, ylab = ylabel,  : 
  'x', 'y' and 'z' lengths differ
```

Ideally I'm hoping R has something equivalent to numpy's nonzero() function that gives you coordinates to all non zero values.

Update, maybe here's some progress:

```
> coords <-which(mydata!=0, arr.ind=T)
> str(coords)
 int [1:889222, 1:3] 40 40 41 40 41 40 41 40 41 40 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "dim1" "dim2" "dim3"
```

But now I'm not sure how to reference dim1, etc.

Comment: this is just a 889222 x 3 matrix, `coords[, 'dim1']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
> source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
> biocLite("rhdf5")
> library(rhdf5)
> mydata <- h5read('/Users/greg/1611_data.h5','dataset_1')
> str(mydata)
 int [1:194, 1:627, 1:269] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
> install.packages("scatterplot3d")
> library(scatterplot3d)
> coords <-which(mydata!=0, arr.ind=T)
> scatterplot3d(coords[,'dim1'],coords[,'dim2'],coords[,'dim3'])
```